# How to map a local JSON string into an object using RestKit 0.24 with RKObjectMapping?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, rkobjectmapping, restkit-0.24.x

I am trying to map a JSON NSString into an object using RestKit 0.24.0 where I have a RKObjectMapping as well as the corresponding dictionary.

Most of the solutions online refer to RestKit 0.22 and below.

Some of the solutions on SO result into app crash.

What is the easiest  way to convert a local string into an object. Consider the following

**CODE UPDATE**

```
    RKMapperOperation *mapper = [[RKMapperOperation alloc] initWithRepresentation:parsedData mappingsDictionary:[RJobObject mappingDictionary]];
    RJobObject * rrrr = [[RJobObject alloc] init];
    mapper.targetObject = rrrr;
    //mapper.mappingOperationDataSource = parsedData;


    [mapper execute:nil];
```

Here , `mappingDictionary` is basically the key-value pair matching between the JSON key and Object variable name
So in the above code whenever I run `execute`, the app crashes.

**Stack Trace**

```
    2015-11-22 09:12:29.193 Help[22427:699579] -[__NSCFConstantString forceCollectionMapping]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1022736a0
    2015-11-22 09:12:29.211 Help[22427:699579] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString forceCollectionMapping]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1022736a0'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d7dc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
     1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000105a14bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
     2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105d850ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
     3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105cdb13c ___forwarding___ + 988
     4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105cdacd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
     5   Help                                0x000000010212f424 -[RKMapperOperation mapRepresentationOrRepresentations:atKeyPath:usingMapping:] + 132
     6   Help                                0x000000010212fe97 -[RKMapperOperation mapSourceRepresentationWithMappingsDictionary:] + 1959
     7   Help                                0x00000001021307a2 -[RKMapperOperation main] + 1330
     8   Foundation                          0x00000001034c4774 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
     9   Help                                0x00000001021310b7 -[RKMapperOperation execute:] + 39
     10  Help                                0x0000000101f62f8e -[AppDelegate fetchJobsFromDB] + 1102
```

**More Details**

Updated to `RestKit 0.26.0` , am still facing the issue.

Basically in `RKMapperOperation.m`, line *333* a `po mapping.forceCollectionMapping` gives an error and it crashed the app.

**ANSWER : Sample Solution**
Use `RKMappingOperation` , as we do not have to specify the keyPath

```
    RJobObject * rrrJob = [RJobObject new];
    RKMappingOperation *mappingOperation = [[RKMappingOperation alloc] initWithSourceObject:jobEntity.dictionary destinationObject:rrrJob mapping:[RJobObject mapping]];
    mappingOperation.dataSource = (id)rrrJob;
    [mappingOperation start];
```

Comment: Show the code you have and give details of the crash, including message and stack trace

Comment: @Wain : added Code, the stack trace, as well some more infor. Please help if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to do 'parsedData' should be a dictionary or array that has been deserialised from the JSON string, and `[RJobObject mappingDictionary]` should be a dictionary where the keys are the source key paths and the values are `RKMapping` Instances defining what to do with the contents.

The idea is that the key paths determine how to drill into the JSON data and the mapping determines how to process the content found there. Your key path might be an empty string if you want to process the whole JSON data.

You might consider using `RKMappingOperation` instead if you want to avoid the key path complexity and you're mapping the whole JSON into a single target object.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting `RKmappingOperation` , have posted the solution in the question itself as **Answer** . One question, though, as you see I had to enter  a `DestinationObject` as well as a `DataSource` as the same object, isn't that redundant. In what case would those two be different?

Comment: IIRC you don't need a data source in this case. Data source supplies instances that need to be created, particularly for core data and multiple instance result sets.